# Programmatically coding 2 UISwitches in 1 Scene

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I am in the process of writing an app, I am using Xcode 11.3.1 / Swift 5 (although this issue is the same in Xcode 10/Swift 4).  Originally when I started writing my app I used the storyboard to place the two UISwitches within the scene and the idea being that if UISwitch-1 is on, then UISwitch-2 is off and vice versa whenever a user clicks on either of them.  The functionality works a treat (well my methods/code/IBActions and IBOutlets) - all is working.

However, I want to programmatically code the UISwitches rather than using storyboard because I want to be able to place the switches at different places on the y-axis depending on the iPhone device type, ie. because an iPhone 11Pro Max is longer than an iPhone 6 then I want to shift the UISwitches down.  I don't believe I can do this in the storyboard, hence wanting to programmatically code them.

The issue isn't the coding of the switches, I have coded them and they work.  However the issue is if I turn UISwitch-1 on then I can't seem to fathom out the code to turn UISwitch-2 off (and vice versa).  I think where I am failing is that I don't know how to call the IBOutlet within the methods to adjust the 'other' switch (ie. the one the user didn't toggle).

The code block below is the code associated with the storyboard technique/method using IBActions and IBOutlets:

'''

```
    // MARK: My UISwitches - toggle between the two UISwitches
    @IBAction func singleUserModeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if dontAllowEditing == false {
            if (sender.isOn) == true {
                setFamilyMode.setOn(false, animated: true)
            } else {
                setFamilyMode.setOn(true, animated: false)
            }
        } else {
            myAlertNoDriverProfile()
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var setFamilyMode: UISwitch!


    @IBAction func familyUserModeSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if dontAllowEditing == false {
            if (sender.isOn) == true {
                setSingleMode.setOn(false, animated: true)
            } else {
                setSingleMode.setOn(true, animated: false)
            }
        } else {
            myAlertNoDriverProfile()
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var setSingleMode: UISwitch!

'''
```

However, the next code block is my code when trying to programmatically program the UISwitches and as I say the code works in that I can display the UISwitches, however when I click on either of the UISwitches that I coded programmatically then I am unable to get them to update the other UISwitch that I created programmatically....

'''

```
 // MARK: Display Switch Buttons
    func displaySwitches() {

        // Determine device type
        if DeviceType.isiPhone6 || DeviceType.isiPhoneX {
            singleUserModeSwitchPositionY = 484
            familyUserModeSwitchPositionY = 525
        }

        if DeviceType.isiPhone6Plus || DeviceType.isiPhoneXs {
            singleUserModeSwitchPositionY = 504
            familyUserModeSwitchPositionY = 545
        }

        // Display UISwitch-1
        let singleUserModeSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 220, y:singleUserModeSwitchPositionY, width: 0, height:0))
        singleUserModeSwitch.isOn = true
        singleUserModeSwitch.thumbTintColor = UIColor.white
        singleUserModeSwitch.tintColor = Colors.jamesBlue
        singleUserModeSwitch.onTintColor = Colors.jamesBlue
        singleUserModeSwitch.setOn(false, animated: true)
        singleUserModeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange1), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        view.addSubview(singleUserModeSwitch)

        // Display UISwitch-2
        let familyUserModeSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 220, y:familyUserModeSwitchPositionY, width: 0, height:0))
        familyUserModeSwitch.isOn = false
        familyUserModeSwitch.thumbTintColor = UIColor.white
        familyUserModeSwitch.tintColor = Colors.jamesBlue
        familyUserModeSwitch.onTintColor = Colors.jamesBlue
        familyUserModeSwitch.setOn(true, animated: true)
        familyUserModeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange2), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(familyUserModeSwitch)
    }

    @objc func valueChange1(mySwitch1: UISwitch) {
        if mySwitch1.isOn{
            print("Switch1 (singleUserModeSwitch) is ON")
            // I think the lines below (where I try an call the .setOn function is where the problem is
            // as I somehow need to call an IBOULET however I don't have one defined because I am
            // programmatically creating the UISwitches
            setFamilyMode.setOn(false, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("Switch1 (singleUserMoeSwitch) is OFF")
            setFamilyMode.setOn(true, animated: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func valueChange2(mySwitch2: UISwitch) {
        if mySwitch2.isOn{
            print("Switch2 (familyUserModeSwitch) is ON")
            setSingleMode.setOn(false, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("Switch1 (singleUserMoeSwitch) is OFF")
            setSingleMode.setOn(true, animated: true)
        }
    }
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Create `setSingleMode` and `setFamilyMode` as the `instance properties` of the ViewController.

**2.** In `displaySwitches()` set their values as `singleUserModeSwitch` and `familyUserModeSwitch`

**3.** Modify `valueChange1(_:)` and `valueChange2(_:)` definitions accordingly.

Here is the code to summarise the above points.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var setSingleMode: UISwitch?
    var setFamilyMode: UISwitch?

    func displaySwitches() {
        //rest of the code...
        let singleUserModeSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 220, y:singleUserModeSwitchPositionY, width: 0, height:0))
        //rest of the code...
        singleUserModeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange1(_:)), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        self.setSingleMode = singleUserModeSwitch

        let familyUserModeSwitch = UISwitch(frame:CGRect(x: 220, y:familyUserModeSwitchPositionY, width: 0, height:0))
        //rest of the code...
        familyUserModeSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange2(_:)), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
        self.setFamilyMode = familyUserModeSwitch
    }

    @objc func valueChange1(_ mySwitch1: UISwitch) {
        print("Switch1 (singleUserModeSwitch) is \(mySwitch1.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
        setFamilyMode?.setOn(!mySwitch1.isOn, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func valueChange2(_ mySwitch2: UISwitch) {
        print("Switch2 (familyUserModeSwitch) is \(mySwitch2.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
        setSingleMode?.setOn(!mySwitch2.isOn, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: BRILLIANT !!  I followed your advice above with 1 slight addition/modification which was to insert   view.addSubview(singleUserModeSwitch) after the .addTarget line, and  view.addSubview(familyUserModeSwitch) after the other .addTarget line and then it works a treat.  Thank You soooo much - I have wasted several nights trying to get this to work (I think my wife is wanting a gift for being so patient) and you've solved my issue in no-time.  I never would have been able to do it.  Thank You so much.

Comment: @JamesLeitch Great. Do accept(tick on left) if it worked worked for you. Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

Make switch in code as following:

```
lazy var setFamilyMode: UISwitch = {
        let familySwitch = UISwitch()
        familySwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // switch property settings
        return familySwitch
}()

lazy var setSingleMode: UISwitch = {
    let singleSwitch = UISwitch()
    singleSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // switch property settings
    return singleSwitch
}()
```

Then add the switch to the view:

```
view.addSubView(setFamilyMode)
view.addSubView(setSingleMode)
```

Add constraints or set frame for the switches as required. If you are setting frame, set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property of switches to true. Save yAxis as per your requirement and change as per your code.

Don't forget to add target for your switches

```
setFamilyMode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange1(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
setSingleMode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChange2(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```